# Calling F# functions from C# without the ugly "Module" suffix

Tags: c#, module, f#, interop

I prefer to separate functions from types idiomatically for F#:

```
[<Struct>]
type Vec2 =
    {
        x   : single
        y   : single
    }

    static member inline (/) (v, scalar) =
        let s = single scalar in { x = v.x / s; y = v.y / s }

[<CompilationRepresentation (CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Vec2 =
    let inline length v = ((pown v.x 2) + (pown v.y 2)) |> sqrt

    let unit v = let l = length v in { x = v.x / l; y = v.y / l }
```

Unfortunately, in C#, the `length` and `unit` functions are `Vec2Module.length` and `Vec2Module.unit`.  **Yuck.**

Apart from defining the functions as static members of `Vec2`, what's the fix for this?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the responses, which are fine solutions addressing the limitation of being stuck with the `Module` suffix.

I don't want to have to make explicit declarations for every module that've authored this way, so I'm just going to stick with static member methods instead of `let`-bound definitions in modules.

As an aside, I wonder if this has been taken into account for future versions of C#.  e.g. When decorating types, methods, properties, etc. with attributes, it's always been acceptable to leave off the `Attribute` suffix.  Perhaps something similar will happen with the `Module` suffix, at some point?

Answer (score 4):

In C# 6.0 you can [access static members without specifying a type name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static). In your case:

```
using static Vec2Module;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a local alias for the class with a `using` directive:

```
using Vec2 = Vec2Module;
```